# Fixed column, fluid content and bottom fixed footer

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a problem and to help you to understand I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2C955/2/).

```
    ________________________________
   |   |                           |
   | F |                           | 
   | I |                           |
   | X |                           |
   | E |                           |
   | D |         CONTENT           |
   |   |                           |
   | B |                           |
   | A |                           |
   | R |                           |
   |   |                           |
   | 3 |___________________________|
   | 0 | FOOTER POSITIONED BOTTOM  |
   |   |    OR DANTE'S INFERNO ?   |
   |___|___________________________|
```

Comment: Interesting exercise!!!

Comment: Thanks for help...now i try ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated Fiddle with the solution:- **http://jsfiddle.net/2C955/40/**

Css Changes that I made:-

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:table;
}
.bar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    display:table-cell;
}
.content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    display:table-cell;
}
.footer {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

HTML:- Added a Main Div

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="bar">Fixed space</div>
    <article class="content">
        <div>here is the content</div>
        <div class="footer">FOOTER NEED TO BE PLACE AT THE BOTTOM...BUT HOW?</div>
     </article>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for reply but it doesnt work becouse it cause some overflow on the right...i don't want the scrollbar-x

Comment: updated the fiddle... changed the ".footer" width from 100% to 90%, as  10% width is given to ".bar"

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that may work for you.

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2C955/38/)**

In this case you absolute position the footer to the left and bottom, and set a `margin-left:` equal to the left `.bar`'s width.

CSS:

```
.bar {
  //existing styles
  width: 30px
}

.footer {
  //existing styles
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px:
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: ...wait a moment: but it's doesnt preserve the '30px width' of FIXED BAR width

Comment: I've updated the fiddle and edited my post to get the fixed bar at 30px

Answer (score 0):

badAdviceGuy and AT-UID have given an answer which would work initially, however if your content above the footer is longer than the displayed page, the footer will ride up the page when scrolling down to view the remaining content.

`position:fixed; bottom:0px; margin-left:41px;` would be needed in your footer class within CSS to keep the footer stuck to the bottom of the page.  Margin-left is 41px in my edit as that is the width of your fixed bar plus 1px for the border.

Updated fiddle CSS:

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0} body,html {width: 100%; height: 100%}
.bar {height: 100%; width: 40px; float: left;}
.content {min-height: 100%;}
.footer {width: calc(100% - 41px);position:absolute;margin-left:41px;bottom:0%;}


/* STYLING */
.footer {color: #FFF; text-align: center; padding: 30px 0;}
.bar {border-right: 1px solid #FFF; color: #FFF; font-size: 10px; text-align: center}
.footer {background: #00cc7a;}
.content {background: #369;}
.bar {background: #639;}
```

Comment: Thanks to you too... but if we use position fixed it's overflows the "Fixed bar"

Comment: Not if you have the `margin-left:41px` in the CSS